# How to get date for nearest Sunday at 15:00 JST?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to get the date for the next coming Sunday at 15:30 JST.
How to do that?

I got a string "Sunday 15:00 JST" and what I need to do is, convert that into the closest coming Sunday 15:00 JST and then turn all of that into Unix epoch time. I might run this code on any day of the week for any day of the week not just Sunday.

Comment: `a.setDate(a.getDate() + 7 - a.getDay())`

Answer (score 0):

### js

```js
    const currentDate = new Date();
    // Sunday - Saturday : 0 - 6.
    const currentDayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay();
    // 1 - 31.
    const currentDayOfMonth = currentDate.getDate();
    // thursday would be: 7 - 4.
    const daysUntilSunday = 7 - currentDayOfWeek;
    // currentDayOfMonth + 7 would be the same day, but
    // next week, then just subtract the difference between
    // now and sunday.
    const nextSunday = new Date().setDate(currentDayOfMonth + 7 - currentDayOfWeek);
    const nextSundayAt3pm = new Date(nextSunday).setHours(15, 0, 0);
```

---

### Moment.js

Using moment.js you can get and set the day of the week
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

All you need to do is create a new Moment, then set the day to Sunday. But..

> If the value given is from 0 to 6, the resulting date will be within the current (Sunday-to-Saturday) week.

Due to it recognising Sunday as the start of the week, you will need to get the Sunday at the start of the current week, then add 7 days on to the date to get the next Sunday from today.

In other words, you add 7 to the days.

```js
    // 0 - 6 sets it to a date of the week within the current week.
    // if you provide a number greater than 6, it will bubble in to
    // later weeks.
    // i.e. 7 = 0 + 6 + 1. where 0 would be the previous Sunday, 6 would
    // set it to Saturday of the current week, then adding an additional 1
    // will set it to the Sunday of the next week.
    const nextSunday = new moment(7); // sets the date to next Sunday.

    // now just set the time to 3pm.
    nextSunday.hour(15);
```

Comment: interesting. I actually get a string "Sunday 15:00 JST" and what I  need to do is, convert that into the next coming Sunday and then turn all of that into Unix epoch time.
I might run this Saturday or any other week and all I need is the date of the upcoming Sunday